# phonegap run ios terminal doesn't work anymore

Tags: cordova, code-signing

I've been getting this error while it was all working perfectly yesterday. I havn't changed anything. I just did phongeap run ios and suddenly I got this message:

Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'

I am able to build through xcode but not my terminal while that was working before. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your `platforms/ios/cordova/build.xcconfig` file, you should see a line that starts with `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY =`. Is there something after the `=`? If not, then the code signing identity has got lost.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem with

```
git clone git://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim.git
```

tho my only goal was to simulate my app in the xcode simulator and not build the app to an .ipa file. So if that is someones goal this won't fix your problem and you still need a valid signing profile or work around it with jailbreak. But to be honest it's worth the 100 dollar for a developers license saves you a lot of hassle.